# Estimating the most important features in a k-means cluster partition

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means, importance

Is there a way to determine which features / variables of the dataset are the most important / dominant within a k-means cluster solution?

Comment: How do you define "important/dominant"? Do you mean the most useful to discriminate between clusters?

Comment: Yes the most useful is what I meant.  I think part of my problem with figuring this out is how to word it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. One usual term to designate this issue in machine learning is [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection).

Comment: One of popular [internal clustering criteria](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/358937/3277), Ratkowski-Lance, can evaluate the "quality" of a cluster partition on the level of each variable separately, thus measuring the contribution or importance of it. It does it on the basis of one-way ANOVA. This is an approach identical or similar to that described below by Frank.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to quantify the usefulness of each feature (= variable = dimension), from the book
[Burns, Robert P., and Richard Burns. Business research methods and statistics using SPSS. Sage, 2008.](http://www.uk.sagepub.com/burns/website%20material/Chapter%2023%20-%20Cluster%20Analysis.pdf) ([mirror](http://www.scribd.com/doc/88429552/Chapter-23-Cluster-Analysis)), usefulness being defined by the features' discriminative power to tell clusters apart.

> We usually examine the means for each cluster on each dimension using
>   ANOVA to assess how distinct our clusters are. Ideally, we would
>   obtain significantly different means for most, if not all dimensions,
>   used in the analysis. The magnitude of the F values performed on each
>   dimension is an indication of how well the respective dimension
>   discriminates between clusters.

Another way would be to remove a specific feature and see how this impact [internal quality indices](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/76095/12359). Unlike the first solution, you would have to redo the clustering for each feature (or set of features) you want to analyze.

FYI:

- [Can a useless feature negatively impact the clustering?](https://www.quora.com/Clustering-statistical-analysis/Can-a-useless-feature-negatively-impact-the-clustering/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt)
- [Can the choice of the measurement units of the features impact the clustering?](https://www.quora.com/Clustering-statistical-analysis/Can-the-choice-of-the-measurement-units-of-the-features-impact-the-clustering/answer/Franck-Dernoncourt)
- [Why vector normalization can improve the accuracy of clustering and classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15779107/395857)
- [What are the most commonly used ways to perform feature selection for k-means clustering?](https://www.quora.com/K-Means-Algorithms/What-are-the-most-commonly-used-ways-to-perform-feature-selection-for-k-means-clustering)

Comment: It is very important to add that in this context one should _not_ take those F (or p) values as indicators of statistical significance (i.e. relative the population), but rather simply as indicators of magnitude of the differences.

Comment: wouldnt the ANOVA imply that each cluster is normally distributed wrt each of its features, and also that each cluster has the same variance amongst each feature ?

Comment: Also, have you considered this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116294/appropriateness-of-anova-after-k-means-cluster-analysis ? Unless I misunderstand something

Answer (score 8):

I can think of two other possibilities that focus more on which variables are important to which clusters.

1. **Multi-class classification.** Consider the objects that belong to cluster *x* members of the same class (e.g., class 1) and the objects that belong to other clusters members of a second class (e.g., class 2). Train a classifier to predict class membership (e.g., class 1 vs. class 2). The classifier's variable coefficients can serve to estimate the importance of each variable in clustering objects to cluster *x*. Repeat this approach for all other clusters.
2. **Intra-cluster variable similarity.** For every variable, calculate the average similarity of each object to its centroid. A variable that has *high* similarity between a centroid and its objects is likely more important to the clustering process than a variable that has *low* similarity. Of course, similarity magnitude is relative, but now variables can be ranked by the degree to which they help to cluster the objects in each cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before and developed two possible methods to find the most important features responsible for each K-Means cluster sub-optimal solution.

1. Focusing on each centroid’s position and the dimensions responsible for the highest Within-Cluster Sum of Squares minimization
2. Converting the problem into classification settings (Inspired by the paper: "A Supervised Methodology to Measure the Variables Contribution to a Clustering").

I have written a detailed article here [Interpretable K-Means: Clusters Feature Importances](https://towardsdatascience.com/interpretable-k-means-clusters-feature-importances-7e516eeb8d3c). GitHub link is included as well if you want to try it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple method. Note that the Euclidean distance between two cluster centers is a sum of square difference between individual features. We can then just use the square difference as the weight for each feature.

[image: Euclidean Distance]

Comment: What is c1 and c2, clusters center?