# Using centroids to find predictive cluster features

Tags: clustering, k-means, scikit-learn, predictor, scipy

I clustered some data (rows: text documents, columns: word frequencies) using the [KMeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.k_means.html#sklearn.cluster.k_means) implementation in Scikit Learn. This, like most other centroid-based clustering algorithms, returns a centroid for each cluster.

I am now trying to identify features predictive of each cluster by simply comparing the value for a certain feature in a centroid to the other centroids. I just subtract the value of centroid 1's feature X from the value of centroid 2's feature X (cf. below) and then sort the differences to see which features have the widest spread and and are thus most strongly correlated with a cluster.

- Does this approach make sense / work?
- If not, why not and what should I do instead? (I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77689/estimating-most-important-features-in-a-k-means-cluster-partition) but
  don't know how exhaustive it is)

I feel that the approach is kind of simplistic, but can't think of a much better way either.

More detailed description of idea, just for clarification:

In a 3 cluster k means, I have the vector for centroid 1 [1,2,0,...]. for centroid 2 [10, 2, 400,...] and centroid 3 [100, 2, 0, ...]. I then subtract feature 1: abs(1-10), abs(1-100), feature 2: abs(2-2), abs(2-2), etc. This I would interpret to mean that feature 1 is strongly predictive of cluster 3 membership, while feature 2 is not very predictive at all. In real life, a feature of course translates into a word. All my features are normalized as feature/total words. 
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, this is sort of how I built my talking teddy bear, which is an AI driven twitter engine of sorts (but its a physical bear).

The next step is of course, don't forget combinations of features being accelerators.  There is a really interesting example on Microsoft's Azure Machine Learning gallery for this doing a clustering of similiar companies which provides a great starting point.  Basically it does is feature hashes each companies wikipedia page into n-grams rolls up counts and fits them into various clusters.  Works pretty darned well, I am using that strategy for identifing similiar companies for a financial application to diversify portfolios.

Advise: Start simple, if its not accurate enough, do more.  If its accurate enough for the ROI, then stop, ship and start the next thing.

Comment: thanks! just so i understand correctly: you'd say the approach is valid, and to get even more accurate one could consider interactions/ correlations between features?

Comment: Exactly.  I typically start with the simplest fastest approach and build from there if necessary.

Comment: Just for good measure, check out the sample in Azure Machine Learnings gallery.  Most of the sample is written in R, but is mostly stock R and therefor fairly easily transferrable to python.