# Which features are most important for K-means clusters (scikit-learn)?

Tags: k-means, scikit-learn

I generated clusters using [Kmeans](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.score) on some biological data, but while the clusters make sense, I would like to know which features were most important for the clustering.  Is there a way to rank or score the contribution of a feature on clustering, either through a sci-kit learn method or other method?

Comment: Does this help? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77689/estimating-most-important-features-in-a-k-means-cluster-partition